# How to rotate camera screen at any angle in android?

Tags: android, rotation, android-camera, screen-rotation

I need to rotate my camera screen at 90, 180, 270, 360 angle in clock wise and anti clockwise for both front and rear camera. I have applied a code block on SurfaceView. Here I am providing the code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    // Set camera preview size,orientation,rotation using parameters
    if (camera != null) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {

            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();

            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);

            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            int degrees = 0;

            switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            }

            int result;
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
            } else { // back-facing
                result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

If any one can tell me how to use in-built camera functionality in my app then also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

before you rotate your camera , you should `release` it

**first**

```
if(mCamera != null){
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

**Second**
if you wanna change the front or rear camera

```
try{
     mCamera = Camera.open(currentFacing);
}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}

if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }
```

**last**

```
if(mCamera != null && mHolder.getSurface() != null){
        try{
           //here change the degress
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem ? not rotate or not change the camera?

Comment: camera is not rotating in all 4 direction and saved image is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Camera.setRotation` in order to properly capture the image and not just set the display orientation for the preview. You should also handle front and back camera differently. The following code should take care of any screen orientation, including different handling for front and back camera:

```
// Set camera rotation (consider display orientation)
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int displayOrientation = display.getRotation();

int rotation = cameraInfo.orientation;
if (Surface.ROTATION_0 != displayOrientation)
{
    if (CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK == cameraInfo.facing)
    {
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation -= 90;
        }
        else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation -= 180;
        }
        if (Surface.ROTATION_270 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation -= 270;
        }

        if (rotation < 0)
        {
            rotation += 360;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation += 90;
        }
        else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation += 180;
        }
        if (Surface.ROTATION_270 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation += 270;
        }

        rotation %= 360;
    }
}

Log.d(TAG, "Camera orientation (" + cameraInfo.orientation + ", " + displayOrientation + ", " + rotation + ")");

cameraParams.setRotation(rotation);
```